# Linked list sorted insert first time try

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to code a c++ program for sorted insert of a linked list. I have given the code below. The problem is when doing my second insert i.e., **insert(&head, 45);** the head value is becoming 0 inside insert() function. I could not insert my second element and getting errors. Can anyone please help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void insert (node** head, int key)
{
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        cout <<"List is empty, Inserting at first posistion"<<endl;
        *head = new node;
        (*head)->data = key;
        (*head)->data = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp;
        temp = new node;
        temp = *head;

        if(key < temp->data)
        {
        cout<<"Key is smaller than first element. Inserting at first and moving"<<endl;
            struct node* ctemp = new node;
            ctemp->data = key;
            ctemp->next = (*head);
            //delete(ctemp);
            return;
        }

        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            if(key > temp->data)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }else
            {
                cout<<"Inserting the data at middle"<<temp->data<<" here"<<endl;
                struct node* temp1 = new node;
                temp1->data = key;
                temp1->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = temp1;
                delete(temp1);
                return;
            }
        }

        if(key > temp->data)
        {
            cout<<"Inserting at last"<<endl;    
            struct node* last = new node;
            last->data = key;
            last->next = NULL;
            temp->next = last;
            delete(last);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void print(struct node *head)
{
    struct node* temp = head;
    cout<<"Element in the list"<<endl;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete(temp);
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    insert(&head, 21);
    insert(&head, 45);
    insert(&head, 5);

    print(head);
    getch();
    delete(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `(*head)->data = NULL;` to `(*head)->next = NULL;` if the list is empty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am making lot of silly mistakes like this in my programming. How to overcome this? any idea?